# Loading and capture iframe with casperjs

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, phantomjs, casperjs

I have an iframe within my page, i tried loading the content of the iframe and then to capture the frame image as:

```
{code}
casper.waitForSelector('button#ldPg', function() {
            this.click("button#ldPg");
            this.echo('I just clicked on ldPg');

casper.withFrame(0, function () {
        casper.thenOpen(mylink, function() {
            });
        }); 

casper.wait(10000, function() {
        this.echo("I've waited for 10 second.");
        });

casper.then(function() {
        this.capture(mydir + 'iframe1.png', {
            top: 0, left: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000
            });
        });
    });
{code}
```

When i run this, i see that the iframe image is captured but blank, the content(such as where to fill in Fname, Lname, email, etc) are not there. I'd like to see the forms in the frame, 
Any better ideas on this will really help.

Comment: Why don't you just open the `mylink` in the page instead of in the iframe of the page? I don't think calling `thenOpen` in the frame context will do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your input, calling thenOpen works form me. But I actually have to use Iframe.

Comment: Can you explain why? As it stands now, you want to load a page in an iframe and take a screenshot of the iframe (with static coordinates).

Comment: Because I will need to integrate the iFrame in my later main page. I just need to make sure the the content of the iframe is loaded correctly. I had notice that mylink is sent to the iFrame with this.click

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Also, please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exactly solved my issues. The reason it was not captured was due to http/https. on my local system, it captures correctly with the code below:

```
casper.waitForSelector('button#loadPage', function() {
  this.click("button#loadSSOPage");
  this.echo('clicked on Load Page');
  casper.wait(10000);          
  casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    var f = document.querySelector("iframe");
    f.src = url;
  }).wait(6000);

  casper.then(function(){
    this.captureSelector(image_dir + "iframe.png", "iframe");
      this.capture(image_dir + "whole_page.png");
     });
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to load a page inside of the iframe, then you're doing it wrong. Calling `thenOpen` (even inside of `withFrame`) will load the URL in the page not the iframe. What you need to do instead is exchanging the source of the iframe:

```
var outerURL = "http://example.com";
casper.thenEvaluate(function(url){
    var f = document.querySelector("iframe"); // the first iframe that is found
    f.src = url;
}, outerURL).wait(2000);
```

Keep in mind that you `thenEvaluate` is the page context which is sandboxed, so you need to pass variables specifically into it. You can't just use variables like `outerURL`.

Then you can use [`casper.captureSelector`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector) to capture the iframe without using some kind of arbitrary rectangle.

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.captureSelector("iframe.png", "iframe"); // again only first iframe
    this.capture("whole_page.png");
});
```